# How do i create separate columns from one column for this Pandas Dataset

Tags: pandas, dataframe

data set:

[image: data set]

In this data set genres column have multiple strings which i want to separate in a column for every movie! can that be possible in pandas or how can we do that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```py
df['genres'].str.split(',',expand=True)
```

Comment: it did not worked!

Comment: I've updated an answer, now it will work. Next time try to provide data in text format, not in a screen